# How to create Azure Function App + Swagger to be used by Logic Apps

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Function App in .Net Core 3.1 that implements Swagger. The Swagger page works as intended. When I try to create a Logic App that uses the **HTTP + Swagger** step, it asks for the **Swagger Enpoint Url**. So far any entries generate error:

```
Failed to fetch swagger with error message: Failed to fetch. Ensure you have CORS enabled on the endpoint and are calling a valid HTTPS endpoint.
```

I have tried the following urls:

- https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger/ui#
- https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger/json
  [image]

I have enabled CORS in the function app, but I do not know what to use for **Allowed Origins**. Docs said to use '*', but that results in:

```
The Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header is not compatible with wildcard origin.
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow CORS as described check-box needs to be off. Now HTTP+Swagger connects and appears to function.

[image]